# VS 2010 Beta 2 problem with System.Web.dll

Tags: visual-studio

All of a sudden i'm getting this error in design view in all my webforms (they all use AJAX.NET)

Error Creating Control-ScriptManager1

"Cannot find type System.Web.UI.IScriptManager in module System.Web.dll"

and

Error Creating Control-UpdatePanel1

"Cannot find type System.Web.UI.IUpdatePanel in module System.Web.dll"

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Replaced System.Web.dll with a partner's and restarted VS